# best way to concatenate rows in sql

Tags: sql, substring, sql-server-2014

Currently, I'm using below code to get summarize the report of the fixed asset audited. At first, this was ok and after 3 years I notice the system is now very slow. I revisit the code and I find that code why the system run slow. when I remove the substring part, the system run faster. is there any work around here?

```
SELECT        
ENTITY
, [ASSET NUMBER]
, [YEAR AUDITED]
, SUM(COUNT) AS AUDITED
, SUBSTRING
    (
        (
            SELECT       
                ', ' + [SCANNED BY].USERNAME
            FROM  dbo.vwAUDITED as [SCANNED BY]
            WHERE vwAUDITED.[ASSET NUMBER] = [SCANNED BY].[ASSET NUMBER] 
                AND vwAUDITED.ENTITY = [SCANNED BY].ENTITY 
                AND vwAUDITED.[YEAR AUDITED] = [SCANNED BY].[YEAR AUDITED]
            ORDER BY [SCANNED BY].[ASSET NUMBER] FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 2, 1000
    ) AS [SCANNED BY]
, MAX(DATE) AS [COMPLETION DATE]
FROM dbo.vwAUDITED
GROUP BY ENTITY
    , [ASSET NUMBER]
    , [YEAR AUDITED]
```

Comment: If you are using SQL server 2017 you can use `STRING_AGG` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I guess you could replace subquery with a join of two instances of table. For more specific answer, please provide us an sql script which will generate test data.

Comment: Replace your `substring` with aggregate function `string_agg`

Comment: Im using sql server 2014 @Magnus

Comment: Another option if < sql server 2017 is to create a custom CLR aggregate for concatenating groups of strings. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregate-invoking-functions?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Magnus I dont know if our our database admin will permit me to do that.

Comment: @DraganJovanović It already crosses that in my mind but I don't know how can I do that

Comment: The definition of the view is rather critical for any suggestions on performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a [user-defined aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-aggregate-transact-sql), as an alternative for the missing [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) function in your version of MS SQL Server.  Then replace the corrolated subquery with the function.

Examples of such a function can be found [here](https://github.com/orlando-colamatteo/ms-sql-server-group-concat-sqlclr) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregate-invoking-functions)

Another way, that doesn't involve a DB admin,  is to use a temporary table with a composite index on the fields that are used to join in the sub-query with the `FOR XML`.

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7d715c0c4cd4f0c018e722f7cf23d477)*

```sql
-- Just assuming the datatypes here, so change them to the correct types.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpAUDITED') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpAUDITED;
CREATE TABLE #tmpAUDITED 
(
  [ENTITY] INT NOT NULL,
  [ASSET NUMBER] INT NOT NULL,
  [YEAR AUDITED] INT NOT NULL,
  [COUNT] INT,
  [DATE] DATE,
  [USERNAME] VARCHAR(100),
  INDEX idx_1 NONCLUSTERED ([ENTITY], [ASSET NUMBER], [YEAR AUDITED])
);

INSERT INTO #tmpAUDITED (
[ENTITY], [ASSET NUMBER],[YEAR AUDITED], [COUNT], [DATE], [USERNAME]
)
SELECT 
[ENTITY], [ASSET NUMBER],[YEAR AUDITED], [COUNT], [DATE], [USERNAME]
FROM dbo.vwAUDITED;

-- Now using the temp table instead of the view.
SELECT
 [ENTITY],
 [ASSET NUMBER],
 [YEAR AUDITED],
 SUM([COUNT]) AS AUDITED,
 SUBSTRING
     (( 
        SELECT ', ' + s.[USERNAME]
        FROM #tmpAUDITED AS s
        WHERE s.[ENTITY] = [AUDITED].[ENTITY]
          AND s.[ASSET NUMBER] = [AUDITED].[ASSET NUMBER] 
          AND s.[YEAR AUDITED] = [AUDITED].[YEAR AUDITED]
        -- ORDER BY s.[ENTITY], s.[ASSET NUMBER], s.[YEAR AUDITED], s.[USERNAME]
        FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 2, 1000) AS [SCANNED BY],
 MAX([DATE]) AS [COMPLETION DATE]
FROM #tmpAUDITED AS [AUDITED]
GROUP BY [ENTITY], [ASSET NUMBER], [YEAR AUDITED];
```

Additionally, it might be worth it to check if the query in the view can be optimized.  Or that adding certain indexes on the tables (used in the view) could improve the performance of the view itself.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to concatenate is:

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = space(0);
select @str += [column] from [yourTable];
select @str;
```

But, your scenario is a little different.
At your case concatenation made pretty well, and performance hit may be caused because of view structure. If you are unable to see view structure, 
you can minimize performance issues by using primary view recordset as CTE, and then perform resuorce-costly contatenate over the CTE instead of view:

```
;with [data] as (
    select [entity], [asset number], [year audited], [username], [date], [count] from [dbo].[vwAUDITED]
)
select 
     [entity]           =   [d].[entity]
    ,[asset number]     =   [d].[asset number]
    ,[year audited]     =   [d].[year audited]
    ,[audited]          =   sum([d].[count])
    ,[scanned by]       =   substring((
                                select 
                                    ', ' + [username]
                                from 
                                    [dbo].[vwAUDITED]
                                where 
                                        [asset number]  =   [d].[asset number]
                                    and [entity]        =   [d].[entity]
                                    and [year audited]  =   [d].[year audited]
                                order by 
                                     [asset number]
                                for xml path('')
                            ), 2, 1000) 
    ,[completion date] =    max([d].[date])
from 
    [data] as   [d]
group by 
     [d].[entity]
    ,[d].[asset number]
    ,[d].[year audited];
```